# Is there a complete list of all US tax-exempt nonprofits in machine-readable format?

Tags: data-request, usa, nonprofit

I've seen they can be purchased from [Guidestar](http://www.guidestar.org/rxg/products/nonprofit-data-solutions/guidestar-data-sets.aspx), but wondered if there was an freely available open data source.

Comment: Guidestar doesn't have complete list of non-profits, right? Just a list of 501 c(3) nonprofits.

Comment: @fgregg it seems like the data contains more than just (c)3s---for example, it includes fraternal orgs which are (c)10s---but you're right in that the answer is probably more narrow than my question is asking. I'm just not sure what the appropriate narrowing is.

Comment: Good point. How about 'all tax exempt nonprofits in the title' and then flesh it out in the body?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [IRS website](http://apps.irs.gov/app/eos/) has an Exempt Organizations Select Check that allows the user to search for organizations that:

- Are eligible to receive tax-deductible contributions
- Were automatically revoked
- Have filed Form 990-N (e-Postcard)

After selecting one of these options, a link will appear to download the entire database of organizations. The databases (plain-text files) are delimited by a vertical bar and should be easily imported into any RDBMS or spreadsheet application.

- Database of organizations eligible to receive tax-deductible contributions (Pub. 78 data).

  [Download page](http://apps.irs.gov/app/eos/forwardToPub78Download.do)

  [Database file](http://apps.irs.gov/pub/epostcard/data-download-pub78.zip) (16 MB compressed, 59 MB raw)
- Database of organizations whose federal tax exemption was automatically revoked for not filing a Form 990-series return or notice for three consecutive years (Automatic Revocation of Exemption List).

  [Download page](http://apps.irs.gov/app/eos/forwardToRevokeDownload.do)

  [Database file](http://apps.irs.gov/pub/epostcard/data-download-revocation.zip) (16 MB compressed, 55 MB raw)
- Database of e-Postcard filings.

  [Download page](http://apps.irs.gov/app/eos/forwardToEpostDownload.do)

  [Database file](http://apps.irs.gov/pub/epostcard/data-download-epostcard.zip) (39 MB compressed, 130 MB raw)

**Sample of the database**

```
000344394|Pandas Foundation Inc.|Salem|MA|United States|PC
000587764|Iglesia Bethesda Inc.|Lowell|MA|United States|PC
000635913|Ministerio Apostolico Jesucristo Es El Senor Inc.|Lawrence|MA|United States|PC
```

The columns (best guess) are:

```
EIN|Name|City|State|Country|Deductibility Status
```

The Deductibility Status is a code that:

> describes the basis for the organization's or organizations' ability to accept tax-deductible, charitable contributions.

[Deductibility Status Codes](http://apps.irs.gov/app/eos/forwardToDeductStatusSearchHelp.do)

Comment: As dwillis points out, the IRS data is only for organizations that have received tax exempt status (or filed a 990). It can take years for organizations to receive this status, but they are allowed to operate as if they are nonprofits in the mean time. The result is that there is **no** list of organizations who are nonprofits in the US. It's pretty common for political groups--legally operating as c4's and c6's--to pop up, run attack ads, and vanish before there's any record that they even exist.

Answer (score 9):

The IRS maintains [data](http://www.irs.gov/uac/SOI-Tax-Stats-Exempt-Organizations-Business-Master-File-Extract-%28EO-BMF%29) on non-profits that have received a tax exemption from the agency, but that doesn't include *every* non-profit organization, only those who have received the tax exemption.

Comment: That's an important point because nonprofits are incorporated at the state level, and may operate locally (and in a limited capacity) with or without federal 501(c)3 status.

Comment: [Disclosure: I'm the co-founder of OpenCorporates]

As noted above many non-profits are incorporated entities, and although we haven't imported the IRS dataset, [OpenCorporates](http://opencorporates.com/) has many non-profits in the database and the info is available through the API. [These](http://opencorporates.com/companies/us_fl?company_type=Domestic%20Non%20Profit), for example, are all the Florida non-profits.

Answer (score 6):

Carl Malamud of PublicResource.org makes the 990 filings of non-profits [available for download](https://bulk.resource.org/irs.gov/eo/readme.html) also [via Wayback Machine (2016)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160912033100/https://bulk.resource.org/irs.gov/eo/readme.html) in bulk, as well as extracts of the first two pages of these filing. These are the same filings that GuideStar uses for to build much of their service, though I do not think they use Public Resource as their primary source.

Answer (score 3):

Also the [National Center for Charitable Statistics](http://nccs.urban.org/) (yes, it exists) provides a decent web interface and [data downloads](http://nccs.urban.org/database/index.cfm) for a wide variety of registered and non-r4egistered orgs. No API that I can see though.

Answer (score 1):

As of this posting, the PublicResource.org link doesn't work, the NCCS datasets are also paid, you must apply for OpenCorporate dataset use.

Below is a more detailed list including Activity and NTEE codes from an IRS page found though a Data.gov search:

https://www.irs.gov/charities-non-profits/exempt-organizations-business-master-file-extract-eo-bmf

It is divided into 4 areas or by state. Here is the document description and the header of the CSV with the fields listed:
www.irs.gov/pub/irs-soi/eo_info.pdf
EIN,NAME,ICO,STREET,CITY,STATE,ZIP,GROUP,SUBSECTION,AFFILIATION,CLASSIFICATION,RULING,DEDUCTIBILITY,FOUNDATION,ACTIVITY,ORGANIZATION,STATUS,TAX_PERIOD,ASSET_CD,INCOME_CD,FILING_REQ_CD,PF_FILING_REQ_CD,ACCT_PD,ASSET_AMT,INCOME_AMT,REVENUE_AMT,NTEE_CD,SORT_NAME

Here is a GitHub project devoted to Open Data for Nonprofit Research:
http://lecy.github.io/Open-Data-for-Nonprofit-Research/

..and code to parse the four separate regional files and combine them into a single Business Master File of all current Exempt Organizations:
github.com/lecy/Open-Data-for-Nonprofit-Research/blob/master/Open_Nonprofit_Datasets/IRS_Business_Master_File.Rmd

Also on DataVerse here:
dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/ZPHJYA