# Where can I get bulk access to IRS 990 filings for US non-profits

Tags: usa, data.gov, nonprofit, irs

There's [another question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/16/is-there-a-complete-list-of-all-us-tax-exempt-nonprofits-in-machine-readable-for) about a list of all nonprofits, and this answer is kind of buried in the answers to that one. Also, this question came up today on the NICAR-L mailing list. It's a common question, so it seemed worth documenting here.

From [resource.org](https://bulk.resource.org/irs.gov/eo/doc/about.html):

> The Internal Revenue Service requires all tax-exempt organizations to
>   file an annual Form 990, “Return of Organization Exempt From Income
>   Tax.” The form details the revenues and expenses, assets and
>   liabilities, and a wealth of information, such as the compensation of
>   executives, any unrelated business income, whether the organization
>   engages in lobbying activities, and the stated accomplishments of the
>   organization.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Resource.org has gathered [reports dating back to 2002](https://bulk.resource.org/irs.gov/eo/readme.html) and says that they process new data monthly. Bulk data can be pulled from [here](https://bulk.resource.org/irs.gov/eo/).

For those who prefer a simple search, the Economic Research Institute (ERI) has [a database of forms](http://www.eri-nonprofit-salaries.com/index.cfm?FuseAction=NPO.Search) dating back to 2003.

In at least one case, a journalist on the NICAR-L list reported back that there was a form in the ERI database which was not in the Public Resource set, so proceed with due caution.

Answer (score 9):

There's also a good list just released from ProPublica starting for 2012 http://projects.propublica.org/nonprofits/

And you can always request a 990 directly from an entity -- it is required to give it to you.

Also, GuideStar aggregates them and allows you to obtain one-at-a-time at no cost. Aggregate data will cost, however.

Answer (score 2):

[Citizen Audit](https://www.citizenaudit.org/) is a good alternative to guide star. 
Edit :

Why ?

Pro :

- The search process is less click hungry.
- Getting several fiscal years at a time is possible on a unique page.
- More fiscal years available for IRS 990. ( generally go until 2005/2006, where guidestar give, in most case, the last 3 years.
- API and bulk access are a possibility ( if you subscribe to a plan )
- On the result page, you have a OCR version of the document, for handy ctrl+f textual research.

Con :

- Some PDF are polluted by banners on top. ( Not-blocking, but annoying. Easily crop-able though )

Comment: Please consider updating your answer to explain more about why Citizen Audit is a good alternative. It will be much more helpful to people who come here trying to learn how to access and use this data.