# 501c compensation dataset?

Tags: finance, nonprofit

I know Guidestar offers a paid product for publicly available, practically hidden,  nonprofit IRS 990 filings.

Does this data live somewhere else?

Comment: See http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/374/where-can-i-get-bulk-access-to-irs-990-filings-for-us-non-profits